# Hybrid container support in ACS-Engine

Tags: azure-container-service

I know that `ACS` does not currently support `Windows` and `Linux Containers` on the same `Kubernetes` cluster. Does `ACS-Engine` currently support `Windows` and `Linux containers` on the same `Kubernetes` cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes hybrid clusters are supported in acs-engine

https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/examples/windows/kubernetes-hybrid.json